# Checkbutton condition in Python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, checkboxlist

Below is my Python script which will check if checkbutton is clicked or not. I am not able to figure it out how I can give if/else statement in checkbutton.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

master = Tk()
master.title ("BOD Checks")

var1 = IntVar()
cb = Checkbutton(master, text='Reboot servers at 3 AM', variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
cb.pack()
cb.select()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. There doesn't appear to be any code related to checking whether the button is clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attributes `onvalue` and `offvalue` in the `Checkbutton()`. You can store this value with either a `StringVar()`, an `IntVar()`, or a `BooleanVar()` (depending on the values used in `onvalue` and `offvalue`) and set the attribute `variable` with the name of the variable. From here, you can check the values with an external `if/else` statement with the `.get()` function of the var you used.

Comment: However, I do not know if this is exactly what you are asking, so please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry for so late reply,i have written a code below but i need a comment box beside the checkbutton. Please help me for doing this.

Comment: You could use the `.place(x=, y=)` instead of `.pack()`. This will allow you to position the two elements next to each other.